# Kapacitor how to create task using template via the rest api?

Tags: kapacitor

I can successfully create templates and tasks using the rest api.

How do i create a task using a template via rest api?

Which endpoint should i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay found out how:

Basically just use the same task rest endpoint and do a post and pass in the json.
In the json you can specify templateId and the vars like below.

```html
{
"status": "disabled"
,"id": "test_task4"
,"template-id": "generic_mean_alert"
,"vars" : {
    "measurement": {"type" : "string", "value" : "cpu" },
    "where_filter": {"type": "lambda", "value": "\"cpu\" == 'cpu-total'"},
    "groups": {"type": "list", "value": [{"type":"string", "value":"host"},{"type":"string", "value":"dc"}]},
    "field": {"type" : "string", "value" : "usage_idle" },
    "warn": {"type" : "lambda", "value" : "\"mean\" < 30.0" },
    "crit": {"type" : "lambda", "value" : "\"mean\" < 10.0" },
    "window": {"type" : "duration", "value" : "1m" },
    "slack_channel": {"type" : "string", "value" : "#alerts_testing" }
}
,"dbrps": [ { "db": "test","rp": "autogen" } ]
,"type": "stream" 
}
```

http://yoururl/kapacitor/v1/tasks